# Trouble retrieving data using PDO syntax, PHP

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, fetchall

I'm brand new to the PDO syntax and I'm liking the learning curve! I'm refactoring code - migrating over from archaic mysqli_* methods.

Predictably, I've run into some snags, being a novice. One of the big ones is (forgive if this is a dumb question) retrieving data from the DB and echoing it out on the page. Here is what I have so far:

```
$getURLid = $_GET['id'];
$idQuery = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_id = :getURLid");
$idQuery->execute(array(':getURLid' => $getURLid));
$idRetrieved = $idQuery->fetchAll(); // This is the part I'm unclear on.
```

When I echo `$idRetrieved['value']` to the page, nothing shows up. I'm missing something or misunderstanding how it works. Maybe fetchAll isn't what I should be using.

If it is, is a loop necessary to retrieve all rows? I was under the impression that fetchAll would loop through them automatically based on what I've read.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `var_dump($idRetrieved);`

Comment: FYI - the `mysqli_*` methods are far from archaic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the doco for [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchall.php) closely. It returns an array of row data.

The type of data representing each row depends on your *fetch mode* which by default is [`PDO::FETCH_BOTH`](http://php.net/manual/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants.fetch-both). This would mean each row is an array with both numeric and associative keys. If you're only going to access the data associatively, I'd recommend using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, eg

```
$idRetrieved = $idQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You would then either need to loop or access each row via its index, eg

```
foreach ($idRetrieved as $row) {
    echo $row['value'];
}

// or

echo $idRetrieved[0]['value']; // assuming there's at least one row.
```

Comment: Thanks. The syntax I had did not include the [0] between $idRetrieved and ['value']. That made it work!